# Same Server, Same PHP, One Site Doesn't Work

Tags: php

I have three domains on the same server (CentOS 7.5.1804), all running WordPress 4.9.8, all running the same version of PHP (7.2.10) and using the same php.ini file (literally, not the same php.ini file copied to each directory, the exact same single file).

The problem is that on only one domain, WordPress thinks that I don't have `php-mysql` installed, yet the other two sites work without issue.

I get the following on the non-working domain:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which
>   is required by WordPress.

Despite the fact that the same `php.ini` file is being used, on the non-working site, the `phpinfo()` report is missing the `mysqli` section.

Domains are: [hummdis.com](http://hummdis.com) (non-working), [dev.hummdis.com](http://dev.hummdis.com) (working), 
[exoticallyplugged.com](http://exoticallyplugged.com) (working).

Thoughts??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've resolved the issue and I'm not 100% sure what fixed it.  However, these are the steps that I took:

1. `yum update`
2. This resulted in:

> Found 3 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:

I'm not going to provide the full update, the point is that I couldn't perform a Yum update because of these issues.

3. I found [this post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2576) and followed the steps.
4. I then found [this post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/centos-111/centos-yum-update-depency-problem-4175526460/) and followed the steps that install `yum plugin-priorities`.

I then tested the site and it's loading without issue.